# Unknown pypcap network interface 'eth0' error with python2 scapy on windows 10 machine

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers, winpcap, sniffing

I am trying to create a simple web monitoring app with scapy(2.4.3), python 2.7 on a windows 10 machine. I also have winpcap(5.0.9983.830) installed.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
def http_header(packet):
    print packet

sniff(iface='eth0', prn=http_header)
```

And this is the error it throws:

```
raise ValueError("Unknown pypcap network interface %r" % pcap_name)
ValueError: Unknown pypcap network interface 'eth0'
```

I also installed .Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 just to be safe, as other solutions pointed out, but had no success. Also tried re-installing scapy, winpcap and recreating the Virtual Environment, but again had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface is not called `eth0` if you are using Windows.

You can use `ipconfig /all` to see all your network interfaces, and you can use the `description` value of the Ethernet interface as the interface name for Scapy. 
So for example in my laptop it is:

```
IFACE_NAME="Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM"
sniff(iface=IFACE_NAME, prn=http_header)
```