# python scapy "unknown pypcap network interface '\\Device\\NPF_Loopback'"

Tags: python, scapy, sniffing

I've an issue with scapy
trying to run the following code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sniff(filter="ip",prn=packet_received, count=10)
```

(assume that packet_received is the callback method)
I expect to get some packets but I got this error:

Unknown pypcap network interface '\Device\NPF_Loopback'

I've seen this thread:
[Unknown pypcap network interface 'eth0' error with python2 scapy on windows 10 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720769/unknown-pypcap-network-interface-eth0-error-with-python2-scapy-on-windows-10-m)
and tried what the guy there said but it didn't worked, anyone know what is the issue?

I dont know if it matter (guess it is according to the forums) I am connected to the internet via external network adapter

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Have you installed Npcap ? Try to update it

Comment: Sorry for the question, but what Npcap will help me? thanks

Comment: If you're on Windows, you need to have Npcap installed to use Scapy, as stated in the documentation: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in cmd if you are using windows:

```
net start npcap
```

That worked for me