# Python fake access point - problem with finding working iface attribute on scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to create a fake access point using Python (`scapy` library) on Windows 10.
I followed a tutorial and everything should work but the only issue is the `iface` attribute. I get an error when I'm trying to put what I saw on the tutorial.
My code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11, Dot11Beacon, Dot11Elt, RadioTap

iface = "wlan0mon"
print(iface)

fake_mac = RandMAC()

# Name of the fake access point
ssid = "free_wifi"

frame = Dot11(type=0, subtype=8, addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", addr2=fake_mac, addr3=fake_mac)

# Beacon layer
beacon = Dot11Beacon()

# Put all properties in the frame
essid = Dot11Elt(ID="SSID", info=ssid, len=len(ssid))

# Connect all layers together
frame = RadioTap() / frame / beacon / essid

# Send the packet to the network every 100ms
sendp(frame, iface=iface, inter=0.1, loop=1)
```

The error in line:

```
sendp(frame, iface=iface, inter=0.1, loop=1)
```

About the `iface`:

```
iface = "wlan0mon"
```

The error:

```
OSError: b'wlan0mon: No such device exists (No such device exists)'
```

What should I put in to make it work?

I tried:

```
iface = conf.iface
```

Not like in the tutorial. It works but I can't see the hotspot on another device.

Comment: Look here, maybe you have a different network interface. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720769/unknown-pypcap-network-interface-eth0-error-with-python2-scapy-on-windows-10-m

Comment: Yes. I don't have an error with it, but I still can't see the AP on another device

Comment: Abdou Rockikz a year ago
Hi again,
Sorry but this tutorial only works in a Linux environment :/ https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/create-fake-access-points-scapy#:~:text=Abdou%20Rockikz%20a%20year%20ago%0AHi%20again%2C%0ASorry%20but%20this%20tutorial%20only%20works%20in%20a%20Linux%20environment%20%3A/

Comment: Bless you. You saved me 100 hours